# Envío de ficheros a una API Rest desde Postman

Tags: postman, webapi

Tengo una API REST a la que quiero enviar un fichero.

En POSTMAN, en el cuerpo, marco 'Binario' y selecciono el fichero que quiero mandar. Tengo un encabezado 'Content-Type', con valor 'application/json'.

En la API, tengo este método POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CargarFichero( [FromBody] byte[] Fichero )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) return Ok();
        else return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

Pongo un punto de parada al principio y lo lanzo. Desde POSTMAN, lanzo la llamada y, al parar en el punto que he puesto, veo que lo que llega a 'Fichero' es null.

¿Por qué no llega nada?

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537641/3613462

Comment: Si utilizas "application/json" en el atributo "Content-Type" del header de la request le estas indicando al servidor que el body  sera un archivo en formato json. en tu caso te sugiero que utilices  "multipart/form-data" para que el servidor entienda que  va a recibir un archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Esteban. Lo pruebo.

Comment: Ahora me da otro error:

"Message": "Este recurso no admite el tipo de medio 'multipart/form-data' de la entidad de solicitud.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Ningún MediaTypeFormatter está disponible para leer un objeto de tipo 'Byte[]' del contenido con el tipo de medio 'multipart/form-data'."

Comment: Justo estoy trabajando en un servicio para subir ficheros (PDF) y he descubierto que lo que mejor me funciona en postman es indicarlo tal cual... `Content-Type:application/pdf`. La diferencia es que mi servicio está escrito en Java

Comment: Gracias, Benito. Voy a intentar también con eso.

Comment: Nada, que no doy con la solución. He probado con varios formatos, pero siempre me da error.